# How to center an element with three others and make them responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How can I center a `div` with 3 `.profilebox` elements on any screens? and make it responsive?

• **Big screens**: One row with my 3 elements 
• **laptop screens**: Two rows (2 elements on the first row, 1 element below) 
• **Tablet and mobile**: 3 rows with one element per row vertically align (centered)

You can check what I want here: [image: Schema]

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 1300px;">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="centerDiv">
       <div class="profilebox ">
         <div class="profileInfo">
             <h3 class="box-shadow">Errore Aethiopia dolorum amni</h3>
         </div>
       </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

And I have 3 `div`s `.profilebox` rendering 3 boxes with my image + title.

CSS :

```
.centerDiv {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
}

.profilebox {
  width: 350;
  height: 210;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-table;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-image: url("");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.profilebox .profileInfo {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 88%;
}
```

With this code, my box is well designed. My **img** and **title** are in the right place. The only thing now is to make it centered in any situation.
I am a beginner in web development, some things may not be meaningful in my code right now. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you considered flexbox or grid layouts? Edit: Though looking at your image, inline-blocks and text-align center may be all you need.

Comment: Is there a reason you picked hand-made-css instead of a beautifull framework like https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ Based on google's  https://material.io/design/ These have basic features like your request included + they are very lightweight

Comment: Use bootstrap classes - `col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12`

Comment: @Jean-Paul I would argue that any library, even a lightweight one is enormous overkill for a layout like this, unless you're also planning on making use of the library's other features.

Comment: what is your target browser?

Comment: Your question leaves quite a few things unclear. What behavior should occur as the screen is sized in one mode? In other words, what should happen with the extra width of the page? D you need your boxes to stay a certain distance apart? Do you need them to stay the same size? Most responsive layouts change the box sizes to fit the screen in some number at a given width.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.profile-box{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  margin:20px;
  border:2px solid #000;
}
.profile-box{
  position: relative;
}
.profile-box p{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile-box">
    <p>profile box</p>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-box">
    <p>profile box</p>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-box">
    <p>profile box</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad, but this requires fixed sizing on the boxes. I'm not a fan of absolutely-positioned paragraphs, though.

Comment: I think this can solve his problem. The absolutely-positioned paragraphs is just to clear the idea

Answer (score 1):

> ***If you would like to use bootstrap***, refer the following -

You could simply use the classes `col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12` as follows -

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      ProfileBox
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      ProfileBox
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      ProfileBox
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- You will finally get 3 elements on extra large screens, 2 on large & medium screens & 1 on small screens in each row.
- To see it ***live with resizing***, check it ***[here](https://jsfiddle.net/yuxcdqtp/)***.

**Note:** You don't need to worry about different browsers if you use bootstrap.

Comment: Throwing a fairly large library at the problem doesn't seem appropriate. I agree that Bootstrap is nice, but not needed (or requested) here.

Comment: @isherwood, You are absolutely right at your perspective & it's a matter of *kb*s' over the network; but it's only a possible solution & we can compress a library to reduce it's size

Comment: @TusharWalzade It really depends on the goal of Gustave, if he wants to create a complete website with components, fancy navs & responsive than yes, bootstrap or any other library for that sake, is a good option, if he just want to understand how it would work in plain CSS, than throwing a library of 20KB+ at the browser doesn't seem like a good idea